# How to set numeric keypad while clicking on texbox with decimal format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want numeric keypad which automatically convert the value of textbox  into decimal format.for example user types 10 it automatically convert .10

Comment: you mean when you click on return then ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
NSString * userInput = textBox.text;
textBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@", userInput];
```

If you need the value as an integer for other use, try:

```
int userInput = [textBox.text intValue];
textBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".%d", userInput];
```

Also, if you need to know the method to do this in real-time, use:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string; {
```

Make sure to return `YES` so that the character gets added! Hope that Helps!

Comment: but how to get numerickeypad while clicking on textbox?i tried this     [txtTotalBill setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];but it doesnt work.

Comment: You can set the keyboard type in the nib file very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Go for keyboardType property of text field and have ur wanted keyboard type. Set that to `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`